# Volvo S40 Starts but won't stay running more than minute. P0339 code

Tags: volvo, s40, p0339

I have a 2004 Volvo S40 that when starts it'll stall.  It'll run for a minute or less before acting like it's starved for air.  Get the codes P0339 which is a crank position sensor.  I have replaced it and I still get the same result.  I've charged the battery also.  The codes read 1st P0339 and a 2nd code that is P0339 with a pd looking symbol next to it.  I've verified the connections on the connector also.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Causes of P0339 Code: Crankshaft Position Sensor 'A' Circuit Intermittent**

Highlighted items are ruled out as already addressed.

Faulty crankshaft position sensor- **replaced**

Crankshaft position sensor harness is open or shorted-**checked**

Crankshaft position sensor circuit ?

Poor electrical connection ?

Signal plate may be damaged ?

Starter motor may be faulty ?

Starting system circuit ?

Dead or weak battery-**recharged**

**Symptoms: Check engine light activation, loss of power, engine stalls**

Try  replacing battery. This might resolve the problem as a weak battery could trigger this code. Maybe starter issue.

This may not give a definitive answer but gives avenues to check next.